# How to use element name when initializing object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get data using ajax function, but my code returns :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected string..

**Javascript :**

```
var myParams = {
  $('#csrf').attr('name') : $('#csrf').val(),
  'module' : 'culinary',
  'id' : '12',
}
$.ajax({
  url: '/uploader/get_list',
  type: 'GET',
  data: myParams,
  success: function(response) {
    reponse = $.parseJSON(response);
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

One of my friends suggested to use this:

```
var myParams = [];
myParams[$('#csrf').attr('name')] = $('#csrf').val();
myParams['module'] = 'culinary';
myParams['id'] = '12';
```

But if I use the second method, the PHP function can't recognize the parameters.

What's the correct way to send parameters to an ajax function?

Comment: `myParams[$('#csrf').attr('name')] = $('#csrf').val();` - this should work. Perhaps you are trying to access this variable with a different name in your php code, than the name you assign it here i.e. the name attribute of `#csrf`. And yes there's a typo as mentioned in an answer below. It should be `var myParams = {};`

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj I'm using the exact same variables in several other ajax function in my code.. so I believe it's not the variable name. the second method only seems to work when it's a POST type ajax. I don't know why :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your creation of the `myParams` object. To create a key using a variable you need to use bracket notation. Try this:

```
var myParams = {
  'module': 'culinary',
  'id': '12',
}
myParams[$('#csrf').attr('name')] = $('#csrf').val();
```

The second example you have doesn't work because you create an array, ie. `[]`, not an object, `{}`.

Also note that if you set the `dataType` property of the request then you don't need to manually parse the response as jQuery will do it for you:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/uploader/get_list',
  type: 'GET',
  data: myParams,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks! worked like a charm! and thank you for the dataType thing

Answer (score 2):

You should define new object `{}` and not new array `[]` :

```
var myParams = [];
```

Should be :

```
var myParams = {};
```

Hope this helps.